# Retriving the String accosiated with a JCheckBox

Tags: java

I have a lottery game problem and I am able to count the number of checked boxes correctly but I do not understand how to get the String number assigned to the JcheckBox. I thought I could use .getText but that did not work. I am not sure if I am using the proper listener.

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JLottery2 extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
private String[] lotteryNumbers = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
        "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19",
        "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30" };
private JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
private JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
private JPanel jp3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 10, 5, 5));
private JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("The Lottery Game!!!!!");
private JLabel jl2 = new JLabel(
        "To play, pick six number that match the randomly selected numbers.");
private FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
private GridLayout gridBase = new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5);
private GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 10, 5, 5);
private Font heading = new Font("Palatino Linotype", Font.BOLD, 24);
private Font bodyText = new Font("Palatino Linotype", Font.BOLD, 14);
private Color color1 = new Color(4, 217, 225);
private Color color2 = new Color(4, 225, 129);
private int maxNumber = 6;
private int counter = 0;
private int[] randomNum;
private String[] userPickedNumbers;

Container con = getContentPane();

public JLottery2() {
    super("The Lottery Game");
    con.setLayout(gridBase);
    con.add(jp1);
    jp1.setLayout(layout);
    jp1.add(jl1);
    jl1.setFont(heading);
    jp1.setBackground(color1);

    con.add(jp2);
    jp2.setLayout(layout);
    jp2.add(jl2);
    jl2.setFont(bodyText);
    jp2.setBackground(color1);

    con.add(jp3);
    jp3.setLayout(grid);
    for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++) {
        JCheckBox checkBox[] = new JCheckBox[lotteryNumbers.length];
        checkBox[i] = new JCheckBox(lotteryNumbers[i]);
        jp3.add(checkBox[i]);
        jp3.setBackground(color2);
        checkBox[i].addItemListener(this);
    }

    setSize(500, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void randNumber() {
    randomNum = new int[maxNumber];
    for (int i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++) {
        randomNum[i] = ((int) (Math.random() * 100) % lotteryNumbers.length + 1);
        System.out.println(randomNum[i]);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JLottery2 frame = new JLottery2();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED && counter < maxNumber) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println("add");
        System.out.println(counter);

    } else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED
            && counter < maxNumber) {
        counter--;
        System.out.println("deduct");
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
    if (counter == maxNumber) {
        System.out.println("max");
        jp3.setVisible(false);
        randNumber();
        System.out.println(userPickedNumbers);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((JCheckBox)e.getSource()).getText()
```

works fine for me with your code.

Comment: What I tried                                                     Object source = e.getSource();                     System.out.println(source);                                            It printed out a line of information but not the String.  Can you explain the difference?

Comment: e.getSource return the JCheckbox instance that is statechanged as an Object. Printing it will call the default toString() method of that object which will print all it properties. My solution will cast it into a JCheckbox instance and will allow you to use the method getText which return the text property.